# Enviar un valor desde un input al controlador codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

Buenas trato de recuperar un valor desde un input de busqueda en el controlador en codeigniter 4 pero siempre me lanza algun error no se si lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta subo codigo:

La vista:

```
        <div class="container">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="form" method="GET" action="<?= base_url().'/busquedas' ?>">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="query" name="query" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
        <input type="submit" id="buscar" value="buscar" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

El controlador:

```
public function busquedas()
{
    //funcion getPost?
    $query =  $this->request->getPost('query');
    echo $query;

    
    return view('busquedas');
}
```

Lo que quiero es recuperar el ID para poder hacer una busqueda pero no obtengo ninguna respuesta, talves estoy cometiendo algun error y se me agotaron las ideas la verdad soy nuevo en codeigniter usualmente uso solo php.
Cualquier ayuda agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Estás enviando un formulario mediante GET pero tratando de recoger los datos mediante POST. Tienes dos opciones dependiendo de lo que necesites.

Modificar la propiedad `method`de la etiqueta `form`, cambiando `GET` por `POST`:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="form" method="POST" action="<?= base_url().'/busquedas' ?>">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="query" name="query" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
    <input type="submit" id="buscar" value="buscar" />
</form>
```

O cambiar la forma en la que obtienes el valor del campo, utilizando `getVar()` o `getGet()` en lugar de `getPost()`:

```
public function busquedas()
{
    // Con getVar()
    $query = $this->request->getVar('query');

    // O con getGet()
    $query = $this->request->getGet('query');
    
    echo $query;

    return view('busquedas');
}
```

Es recomendable que le eches un vistazo a este enlace, donde viene todo explicado: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#id3